# properly freeing resources in a view that belongs to an adapter

Tags: android, listview, memory-leaks, android-view

My **list adapter** creates some `Views` (both normal views and header views) that **use constantly-running timers** to cycle their displayed image.

I wonder what's the appropriate way to deallocate those timers and other view-related resources, i mean, the best practice to know that an Item `View` (created by `Adapter.getView`) is no more visible/needed, or has been recycled, or de-attached, or even their parent widget is not in use.

I'm ideally looking for a method / event / listener in the `View` itself, rather than the parent Widget having to delegate an event. I'd like to know

- When the `View` is given to the recycler (ie- it has exited screen on a fling, etc)
- When the `View` can be destroyed (ie- the containing widget has been destroyed)

So far I think I haven't found the appropriate, fail-proof event, if any.

I tried `View.onAttachedToWindow()` / `View.onDetachedFromWindow()` but, opposed to `onAttachedToWindow` that seems it's always properly called, `onDetachedFromWindow` is not. **It seems it's only called when a recycled view is about to be reused**, but not on other cases like when the `View` enters the recycling pool (exits screen), or when the widget is destroyed, or even when the activity is finished.

Any suggestion?

EDIT:

I have been doing some tests, and found that `onDetachedFromWindow` on the **parent widget** IS reliable. At the moment my solution is to **propagate that event to the adapter**, which in turn finds the views on screen (`getFirstVisiblePosition`...) and manually triggers an `onDetachedFromWindow` with the code below, but, you know, this is very ugly. I'm sure there's a better way.

```
// ugly function to trigger an onDetachedFromWindow to any view
// leeched from com.tonicartos.widget.stickygridheaders.StickyGridHeadersGridView
public static void detachHeader(View header) {
    if (header == null) { return; }

    try {
        Method method = View.class.getDeclaredMethod("dispatchDetachedFromWindow");
        method.setAccessible(true);
        method.invoke(header);
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        throw new RuntimePlatformSupportException(e);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        throw new RuntimePlatformSupportException(e);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        throw new RuntimePlatformSupportException(e);
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        throw new RuntimePlatformSupportException(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

RecyclerView.Adapter has a method to notify you when a view is recycled. Have a look at

public void onViewRecycled(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder);

Comment: This is only called when the view of the item is going to be recycled (re-used). So when just changing to another acitivity will not call this method. Changing the activity back leading to the recyclerview will recreate everything. This leads to a memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

### a) Leave the activity - flush everything in the adpater

May a proper way is to use the `onStop` Method of the surrounding activity. There you do have a reference to the adapter. In the adapter you can provide a `flushAllResources()` Method which you call from the activity.
This will work for cases where one leaves the activity.

```
@Override
public void onViewRecycled(@NonNull final MyViewHolder holder) {
    flushAllViewRefreshHandlers();
}
```

### b) View is gonna be re-used due to scrolling - flush the old data as the view was used previuously

Additionally in the `onViewRecycled` Method (as mentioned previously) you should also flush your resources.
This will work for cases where single items/views of the recycler are going to be re-used (recycled) for other entities. In this case you may only flush data of the specific view/entity and not all of the whole adapter.